# Multivariate intermediate value theorem

Tags: calculus, continuity

The following claim seems true for me:

For any continuous function over reals $f(\vec{x})$, if $f(\vec{x})=c$ has no zero, then either $f(\vec{x})>c$ for all $\vec{x}$ or $f(\vec{x})<c$ for all $\vec{x}$.

However, my calculus is a bit rusty, and I am wondering from which this claim follows? (For univariate functions, this follows from the intermediate value theorem?)

Comment: Just consider the values of $f$ along the straight line between a point with a value below $c$ and one with a value above $c$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard proof of the one variable mean-value theorem works here as well. The relevant idea is that if $f$ is continuous, then $f$ maps connected sets to connected sets.

So suppose you have $x$ and $y$ such that $f(x) < 0$ and $f(y) > 0$. Then take a connected open set $U$ containing both $x$ and $y$. As $f$ is continuous, we know $f(U)$ is connected and contains both a positive and negative number, and thus also contains $0$.

Thus your multivariate intermediate value theorem is true.